# Cascading Dropdown get reset to zero index on save click event

Tags: asp.net, web, datagridview

I have created all my Drop-downs and cascading Drop-down on rowdatabound event of grid view asp.net dynamically 
My Problem is when i select any value from cascading drop down and save.
Only the 1st value get save 1st time 
Scenario is in country drop down suppose,
I have selected India so states will populate and them if i select some state say Gujarat then if i press save and come back  the value save is not Gujarat but the 1st value in drop down
I have to call bind grid on every post back

In Rowdatabound event

```
     if (value.Equals("Dropdown"))
                {
                    int attributeid = Int32.Parse((e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView).Row["attributeid"].ToString());
                    string a = (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView).Row["attributevalue"].ToString();
                    DropDownList dp = new DropDownList();
                    dp.ID = attributeid.ToString();
                    dp.CssClass = "gridtextbox";
                    dp.EnableViewState = true;
                    getDropdowns(dp, attributeid);

                    String attributevalue = (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView).Row["attributevalue"].ToString();
                    int cascadingid = Int32.Parse((e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView).Row["cascadingid"].ToString());


                    if (cascadingid != 0  )
                    {

                        dp.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(Bind_gridchild);
                        dp.AutoPostBack = true;

                    }

                    e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(dp);
```

And my getdropdown() method bind the data for 1st drop down
 On selectedIndexchange event

```
 if (inputtype.Equals("Dropdown"))
                {
                    DropDownList dp = new DropDownList();
                    dp = (DropDownList)Vendorform.Rows[Int32.Parse(cascading)].FindControl(cascading);
                    //dp.EnableViewState = true;
                   // dp.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
                    string dummy = dp.ID;

                    using (dbForcastingDataContext db = new dbForcastingDataContext())
                    {

                            dp.DataSource = db.usp_vm_etl_getdropdownvalues(Int32.Parse(cascading), Int32.Parse(selectedValue));
                            dp.DataTextField = "attributeSelectionValue";
                            dp.DataValueField = "attributeSelectionValue";
                            dp.DataBind();
                            // dp.Items.Insert(0,new ListItem("Select", "0"));

                    }

                }
```

Comment: Share the code. Is it ASP.NET Web Form or MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to store that selected value in hidden field using Javascript because you have to call bind grid on every post back
and after post back selected value will be 1st value in ddl.

```
<script >
function CallButtonClick() {
            var e = document.getElementById("<%=DropDownList1.ClientID %>");
            var x = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
            document.getElementById("HiddenField1").innerText = x;
           __doPostBack("<%=DropDownList1.UniqueID %>", "");
        }
 </script>
```

Add HiddenField control in your page

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
```

Your Code

```
using (dbForcastingDataContext db = new dbForcastingDataContext())
         {
                dp.DataSource = db.usp_vm_etl_getdropdownvalues(Int32.Parse(cascading), Int32.Parse(selectedValue));
                dp.DataTextField = "attributeSelectionValue";
                dp.DataValueField = "attributeSelectionValue";
                dp.DataBind();
                if (HiddenField1.Value != null)
                {
                  DropDownList1.SelectedValue = HiddenField1.Value;
                }
                HiddenField1.Value = string.Empty;

        }
```

DropDownList.

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onchange="return CallButtonClick();" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: this does not work , my problem is my controls are created and binded in onrowdatabound of gridview and there my casading gird also rebinded and the value which was selected is lost

Comment: You need to add above code inside onrowdatabound where dropdownlist will bind.If not solved then update exact code.